# Android Facebook SDK release key hash doesn't work

Tags: android, facebook, hash, key, release

I have a problem with my app facebook key hashes on release build.
I have generated release key hash from keystore file with this command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

and pasted it to developers.facebook page. However, when I try to login, it says that key hash which is shown doesn't match any of listed in developers page. If I paste that shown key hash, facebook login will work, but I want facebook to work for other users without putting their key hashes to developer page.
How could I do that?

Comment: HAVE YOU CHECKED THE OPTION TO MAKE YOUR APP PUBLIC?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your app public for other devices to work.

Go to your facebook developer console and select your project(app) from app section.Then in status and review turn on the option--Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?.

You will need an email id to turn it on so add one if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks, but that means that I need to submit my app for approval.

Comment: @Linis then probably you are doing something wrong.Check that your key generated is with the released sha1 and also check that you are using the correct app id in your app.